Zooming in/out on a sphere while the point position under cursor stays invariant
Just like in google earth, my game renders a sphere with the camera moving around it. The sphere has the radius 1 and is centered at the coordinate origin. The camera is always targeting the sphere center and its up-vector is the z-direction. Or to speak in code, my view matrix is lookAt(cam_position, vec3(0), vec3(0,0,1)) and the perspective matrix is a run of the mill one.
Now what I want is hat when the player uses the mouse wheel, the camera should 1) zoom in/out (ie distance from sphere reduced) and 2) the point on the sphere under the cursor should still be at the same screenspace position after (and ideally: during) the movement.
Naively I tried implementing this by just moving the camera along a line towards the point the cursor points at. But I soon discovered that really any linear movement of the camera doesn't seem to fulfil that constraint. I want to stress that when moving the camera, it always targets the sphere center, that's why moving in a straight line towards the cursor point isn't enough.
This exact behavior is implemented in google earth, so it's apparently possible. But I don't know how. I'm aware that speaking in math terms, this can be formulated as the screenspace-resolved coordinates of that point stay invariant under the movement transformation. But I doubt that writing that equation down helps me solving this. I'm not even sure what the resulting camera path would be like: A circle arc or something entirely different. Ideally this would just be a linear transformation from some special origin, but I have no idea.
For illustration purposes, here's a setup showing the camera on a straight line to a closer "orbit", the red dot marking an example point I would like to stay constant on screen. Note again that this path is incorrect, it was just my attempt.

This is the resulting view from the camera. You can see the red point in the same screenspace position at the start and end, but not in between.

And as a correct example, everyone is invited to use the mouse wheel on earth.google.com.
Alternatively, the problem can be thought of from the perspective of the camera. We can make it at origin, looking "up" (in 2D to make things simpler) at the circle. Zooming it would make the circle come down (closer). To keep a point fixed, it would still need to be on the same "line", requiring a rotation of the sphere to correct. Maybe this is helpful, not sure. Illustration where the closer circle required ~45° rotation to still match have the point invariant for the camera:

edit: to make things more concrete, ideally I'd prefer if the solution would be in the form of a matrix transformation. I suspect that it can be formulated like that instead of explicitly writing down and equation for the correct path. But I don't know how/if this is solvable, so any pointers are welcome

Let us state the problem in polar coordinates. Given the two angles phi and psi and the distance d, your camera position C is (there are several options, of course):
        / cos phi * sin psi \
C = d * | cos phi * cos psi |
        \ sin phi           /

Equivalently, the camera's right, up, and forward vectors are:
    / -cos psi \
r = |  sin psi |
    \     0    /

    / -cos phi * sin psi \
f = | -cos phi * cos psi |
    \ -sin phi           /

    / -sin phi * sin psi \
u = | -sin phi * cos psi |
    \  cos phi           /

So far, so good. We can now model the projection with the help of these vectors (assuming you have a standard central projection). We are not actually doing a full projection but only the parts we need. The view-space coordinates (x, y) of a world-space point p are (skipping some intermediate steps, ∘ is the dot product):
      p ∘ r
x = ---------
    p ∘ f + d

      p ∘ u
y = ---------
    p ∘ f + d

The basic idea to solve your problem is then: Calculate x and y when you start the camera movement. You want your camera to transition from a known distance d_start to a known distance d_end. The other coordinates phi and psi are only known at the start position. Ideally, you would solve the above equations for these coordinates. However, the system of equations does not seem to have a compact closed-form solution (at least, I could not find one). Hence, an alternative is to use a numerical approach. Since you are moving in small steps anyway, a simple approach like gradient descent should work reasonably well. So what you can do exactly:
Initialize by calculating x and y and store them in x_obj, y_obj
Store the current phi and psi coordinates
Animate d from d_start to d_end:
    do
        calculate the objective o = { x_obj - x, y_obj - y }^2 
        calculate the gradient ∇o w.r.t. phi and psi
        if o < some threshold then exit loop
        (phi, psi) -= step * ∇o
    loop
   Position the camera at (phi, psi, d)
Next animation step

To calculate the gradient, you might want to consider the use of an auto diff library to avoid having to calculate the derivatives by hand.

Hey, thanks for the answer. Yeah I thought about stating the problem implicitly. I think it might even be possible to state it infinitesimally, ie getting a vector of change. But that brings its own can of problems with it regarding numerical trouble, repeatability etc. For the moment I've abandoned the idea of doing this for a lack of a "proper" solution. But many thanks again for your effort!
